# Maven java исполняемый jar файл с параметрами

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, поиск, jar

У меня есть файл csv, мне нужно с помощью команды mvn clean package собрать проект и получить jar файл. Пользователь запускает приложение, указывая параметром номер колонки по которой требуется поиск:
java –jar name.jar 2, // запуск приложения в режиме поиска по второй колонке

После запуска программа выводит в консоль предложение ввести текст. После ввода программа выводит список всех строк из файла, вторая колонка которых начинается на «Bo», отсортированных по этой
колонке.

Сделал так, чтобы jar файл компилировался. Main тоже сделал, покажу, но он 100% не правильный.
При вызове команды java –jar name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 2
Выводит ошибку Error: Unable to access jarfile name.jar
Все решения из интернета по типу "Обновите java" сделаны.

Вот main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String data = null;
    while (!Objects.equals(data, "!quit")) {
        data = in.nextLine();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull
                (Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/airports.csv")));
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            while (reader.ready()) {
                String tmp = reader.readLine();
                if (tmp.startsWith(data)) {
                    System.out.println(tmp);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>name</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.java.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня программа работает, по крайней мере запускается. Я на 99% уверен что просто не тот путь в jar'нику (т.к. сам так ошибался). Покажите, пожалуйста, выводы команд pwd (echo %cd% для windows) и ls (dir в windows, если не ошибаюсь) и саму команду.

UPD:
только сейчас заметил, что в программе нигде не читаются параметры, так что в команде
`java –jar name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 2`
параметр "*2*" писать бессмысленно

UPD2:
уже могу предположить что команда выполняется из корня проекта, попробуйте `java –jar target/name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: При такой команде java –jar target/name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Выдает вот такую ошибку:
Error: Could not find or load main class ?jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ?jar

Comment: Отлично, значит jar файл нашёл, но не нашёл класс. ClassNotFoundException - класс не найден. проверь что класс Main в пакете com.java, т.е. путь до Main.java такой: src/main/java/com/java/Main.java. А вообще почитай про пакеты и import'ы, например тут: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.2.php.

Comment: Исправил путь, теперь src/main/java/com/java/Main.java, но ошибка все равно такая же.
И можно сразу еще один вопрос пожалуйста,
"только сейчас заметил, что в программе нигде не читаются параметры, так что в команде java –jar name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 2 параметр "2" писать бессмысленно"
Что нужно сделать, чтобы параметр считался?

Comment: Хмм, а в Main.java есть `package com.java;` в самом начале? А про аргументы - у метода main есть параметр String[] args, это список всех переданных аргументов. т. е. двойка будет лежать в args[0] (только в формате строки).

Comment: D:\folder\project\src\main\java\com\java\Main.java
Это полный путь, скопированный из intellij idea/

Comment: Так это, в Main.java первая строка это `package com.java;`? Если нету, добавьте, и всё должно заработать. :)

Comment: Эта строчка тоже имеется)

Comment: эуу, такс... А что выводит эта команда: `java -jar target/name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.java.Main`?

Comment: После ввода такой команды все заработало. Можно ввести какое-то значение и тогда он выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
        at com.java.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Если что, это он просто не нашёл файл /src/airports.csv. (он должен быть src/main/resources/src/)